# Can't persist an entity with two foreign keys pointing to same table

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I have three database-tables mapped as three entities:

- Employee
- Room
- EmployeeToRoom

```java
public class Employee implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "\"id_emp\"")
private Integer id_emp;

@Column(name = "\"name\"")
private String name;

@Column(name = "\"surname\"")
private String surname;

...

}
```

```java
public class Room implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "\"id_room\"")
private Integer id_room;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "\"id_roomtype\"")
private RoomType type;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "\"id_floor\"")
private Floor floor;

...

}
```

```java
public class EmployeeToRoom implements Serializable {

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "etr_seq", sequenceName = "etr_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "etr_seq")
@Column(name = "\"id\"")
private Integer id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "\"id_room\"")
private Room room;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "\"id_emp\"")
private Employee employee;

/* Who created/updated record in DB */
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "\"who\"")
private Employee who;

/* When was record created/updated */
@Column(name = "\"when\"")
private Timestamp when;

private static final long serialVersionUID = -2059394677268317393L;

...
}
```

So I'd like to store info which employee works in which room (and also who and when created database record).

I created Managed Bean with listener:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class EmployeeToRoomBean implements Serializable {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
     final javax.persistence.EntityManager em = EntityManager.getEm();
     private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmployeeToRoomBean.class);
     private EmployeeToRoomDaoJPA ETRdao = new EmployeeToRoomDaoJPA();

...

    public void updateListener() {
        TimeStampMaker tsm = new TimeStampMaker();
        ...
        /* Some issues */
        ...
        EmployeeToRoom etrToadd = new EmployeeToRoom();

        etrToadd.setRoom(getEditedRoom());
        etrToadd.setEmployee(employee);
        etrToadd.setWho(UserLogin.getUser().getEmployee());
        etrToadd.setWhen(tsm.getTimestampAsObject());

        ETRdao.create(etrToadd);
        }
}
```

If I try to make logger output with set values (setRoom(), setEmployee(), setWho(), setWhen()) everything is OK - not null values.

And finally I have:

```
public class EmployeeToRoomDaoJPA implements EmployeeToRoomDao, Serializable {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
      private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmployeeToRoomDaoJPA.class);

      ...

      @Override
      public void create(EmployeeToRoom entity) {
            EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
            try {
                tx.begin();

                this.log.info("Creating new EmployeeToRoom entity:");
                this.log.info("Room: " + entity.getRoom().getId_room());
                this.log.info("Employee: " + entity.getEmployee().getId_emp());
                this.log.info("Who: " + entity.getWho().getId_emp());
                this.log.info("When: " + entity.getWhen().toString());

                em.persist(entity);
                tx.commit();
                this.log.info("done inserting obj " + entity.getId());
            } catch (PersistenceException pe) {
                if (tx != null) {
                   tx.begin();
                   tx.rollback();
                }
              throw pe;
            }
      }
}
```

**And there's my problem**. I just receive an PersistenceException with message that query violated not-null constraint of column Who in EmployeeToRoom entity.

But... I added logger output immediatly after beginning a transaction. There's not null value in entity.getWho().getId_emp().

I can't solve this problem for several days. As you can see I have two foreign keys in EmployeeToRoom entity/table to Employee entity/table - property Employee and property Who. Can it be my problem? Or everything else is wrong?

Many thanks for any advices.

(Postgres DBMS, Apache Tomcat, Hibernate, JSF2/Mojarra)

Comment: Two things: It would be nice to see the log of the SQL generated by Hibernate and the error message; and, if you are using JPA 2.0 and all your database objects are lower case and need to be delimited, you can use the "delimited-identifiers" setting in your persistence-unit-defaults (instead of including escaped quotes in all your column names etc.).